# ¿Cómo transformar Archivos de audio en C# (WAV => MP3)?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Buen día, estoy intentando crear un programa de consola con *C#* en donde he intentado implementar LAME dll pero es muy ambigua su información y además de obsoleta, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de realizar el proceso de transformación de audio de WAV a MP3.

```
string comando = $"/c ffmpeg -i {fi.FullName} {NombreDirectorioOrigen} \\ {NombreDirectorioDestino + fi.Name}{formato}";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
    Arguments = comando

};
```

Esto es lo que tengo al momento de traer todos los archivos .WAV de una carpeta y que los quiero transformar (convertir) a MP3.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, deberias poner lo q has intentado

Comment: Compartenos el valor de `comando`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude realizar el proceso de transformacion de WAV a MP3 importando un nuget de Naudio.Lame y usando el siguiente codigo...

```
// Convert MP3 file to WAV using NAudio classes only
public static void MP3ToWave(string mp3FileName, string waveFileName)
{
    using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3FileName))
    using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(waveFileName, reader.WaveFormat))
        reader.CopyTo(writer);
}
```